# A generic List.Count gives a System.ArgumentException

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following class:

```
public class SimContactDetails2G
{
    public String AbreviatedName { get; set; }
    public String DialingNumber { get; set; }
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public String Surname { get; set; }

    public SimContactDetails2G()
    {

    }

    public SimContactDetails2G(String name, String phoneNumber)
    {
        AbreviatedName = name;
        DialingNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

}
```

i want to create a list of the above objects. so i do,

```
List<SimContactDetails2G> simContactDetails2GToBackUp = new List<SimContactDetails2G>();
```

However, when I try to retrieve the count of items on the variable "`simContactDetails2GToBackUp`", it gives the folwing error:

> `Count =`
>   `'((System.Collections.Generic.List<T>)(simContactDetails2GToBackUp)).Count'`
>   `threw an exception of type`
>   `'System.ArgumentException'`

the program does not crash, but I cant access the count property. I can add items on the list, the list is populated. But I can't get the count. Any idea for this strange behaviour?

Comment: It's only when you're debugging , isn't ?

Comment: Where in your code do you access `Count`? That may be key here...

Comment: Have you unwittingly defined a variable called "Count" and the compiler is getting confused about which Count you're referring to?

Comment: There's a thread in MSDN forum, doesn't seem very helpful, but maybe it'll give you a hint: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/056df125-5d66-4068-a268-00b736967770

Comment: @Remi bourgarel. You are right, i get it only during debugging. The program does not crash at this line.

Comment: @NeerajC : can you add your exact code and the line where you put your breakpoint ?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you casting to `List<T>` instead of `List<SimContactDetails2G>`?

Comment: i am not casting to List<T>. its the error that i have posted exactly as i get it when debugging.

Answer (score 0):

use it like:

```
int Count = simContactDetails2GToBackUp.Count; //you can use it without any typecast
   or
int Count = ((System.Collections.Generic.List<SimContactDetails2G>)(simContactDetails2GToBackUp)).Count;//you will have to specify its type while performing typecast.
```

i have tested it, its working with above code.
but first one is preferable. because there is not need to typecast.